# I want to add together the numbers of a nested array

Tags: javascript

This is what I came up with:

```js
var nestedArr = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6]]];

function sumTotal() {
 for(var i = 0; i < nestedArr.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < nestedArr[i].length; j++) {
   for(var k = 0; k < nestedArr[i][j].length; k++) {
    var arrNumSum = nestedArr[i][j][k]; 
    arrNumSum += arrNumSum;

    return arrNumSum;   
   }
  }
 } 
}

sumTotal();
```

Comment: What value do you expect at the end?

Comment: That code returns `nestedArr[0][0][0]` (multiplied by 2)

Comment: What results are you trying to get? What results do you actually get from this code?

Answer (score 7):

You can instead create recursive function using `reduce()`

```js
var nestedArr = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6]]];

function sum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(r, e) {
    return r + (Array.isArray(e) ? sum(e) : e)
  }, 0)
}

console.log(sum(nestedArr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting `arrNumSum` each time through the loop. Moreover, you're returning too soon, right after the first iteration. Try this instead:

```js
var nestedArr = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6]]];

function sumTotal() {
 var arrNumSum = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < nestedArr.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < nestedArr[i].length; j++) {
   for(var k = 0; k < nestedArr[i][j].length; k++) {
    arrNumSum += nestedArr[i][j][k];
   }
  }
 } 
 return arrNumSum;   
}

console.log(sumTotal());
```

Comment: I understand that you're only fixing the OP's code, but how about showing them a better way?

Comment: I saw that others were already doing that (and are rightly getting more upvotes). It might still be instructive for the OP to see where they were going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recusive call of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with a named function as callback.

```js
var array = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6]]],
    total = array.reduce(function add(r, a) {
        return Array.isArray(a) ? a.reduce(add, r) : r + a;
    }, 0);

console.log(total);
```